# Rails and Active Admin Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I build a simple ecommerce app and i am using active admin for administration panel. My problem is this.

i have two models orders & order_items. order_items saves the orders products. The association is order -> has_many order_items & order_items -> belongs_to orders.

I have this code in active admin but i can't see the items of an order(blank).

```
 index :title => 'orders' do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column "value", :subtotal
  column "tax", :tax
  column "shipping", :shipping
  column "total value", :total
  column "status", :order_status_id 
  column "created_at", :created_at 
  column "updated_at", :updated_at
  column "order_items", :order_items
  actions
end
```

I can reach order_items throw console so there is no problem with the model associations.

Comment: Are you sure the order actually has order_items attached to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
index :title => 'orders' do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column "value", :subtotal
  column "tax", :tax
  column "shipping", :shipping
  column "total value", :total
  column "status", :order_status_id 
  column "created_at", :created_at 
  column "updated_at", :updated_at
  column :order_items, sortable: true do | item |
    item.id # this could be any attribute attached to the order_item table 
  end
  actions
end
```

Comment: You helped me a lot but i choose another way. I create a different menu for order_items and put a link to orders that automatically filter the order_items and show only this order items.  This is the code:        ``column "products", :order_item  do | i |
        link_to i.order_items.count, admin_order_items_path('q[order_id_equals]' => i.id)
      end``

Comment: awesome glad I could help